# as3 document class doesn't load

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a document class in my project and after I update it and put it on server the flash player loads the old version. It doesn't save in the cache memory which I clean every time I test the results, but seems to work when I change the name and modify the swf's doc class. Any idea how I could get around this? My document class is in the same folder the swf is, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must recompile your .swf locally and reupload that to your server. Any classes (.as files) are compiled into the .swf and not loaded by the .swf  In fact, there's no reason to put any source code on a server, just like there's no reason to upload a .fla file.